# Can I update an iOS app to add advertisements?

Tags: ios, app-store, iad

Does Apple reject updates to apps that do little other than implementing iAds? Has anybody done this? There's nothing explicitly stated in the guidelines, but I understand how it could be seen as annoying, and Apple has a "we'll know it when we see it" rule about bad App Store submissions.

My update would add a new feature and fix a few issues too. I don't care about losing users because the app in question is my app for testing the waters before I release my serious one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies.

Comment: From a business perspective, I'd hope Apple doesn't do this, as they'd be missing out on revenue! You're correct in saying there's nothing in the App Store guidelines prohibiting this. You should make it through the review process a-ok (assuming you've already made it through with the same product in the past, less the ads).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about Apple's business priorities. I'm also surprised it got approved in the first place, considering the bug where it quits if you open Control Center and how overall low-quality it is. As I said, this isn't my main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your app solely to add iAd banners. You also say you are going to fix issues as well, so even more reason why it shouldn't be rejected.